# fbprophet taking >3 days to run. Am I exploring too many params at one go?

Tags: python, facebook-prophet

I ran this code 3 days ago, and I do see progress. I'm not sure if these set of params should be taking this long?

I've halved the params from before, because I thought it took too long, so I hoped that this set of params would run faster, but 3 days is really long so I'm starting to question whether I'm doing this right or whether I'm missing something.

I got the code from the fbprophet documentation itself, so it may not be an issue with the code(?).

In case it matters, I'm predicting solar energy potential for the last month of 2015, based on 10 year's worth of data. Dataset is sourced from kaggle.

[image]

Comment: fbprophet can be rather slow, especially for monthly data. In any case I'd always start with running and tuning the model yourself: validate the output, look at some graphs, etc. before you do any kind of hyperparameter tuning.

Comment: Wise advice! I ended up doing that and it ran much faster, with decent results. So I'm happy for now.